# I a trying to update my server to php7.1 version but I am facing an issue

Tags: linux, server, php-7.1

I have been trying to update the server for the latest PHP version 7.1 but I am being unsuccessful. I am getting the following error when I try apt-get upgrade

**E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.**

Any help with a lead to help me finish my update is really appreciated.

Need to update PHP from 5.6 to 7.1 but I am unsuccessful just by doing an apt-get update && an apt-get upgrade

Answer (score 1):

Try ondrej PHP

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y php7.1
```

Comment: I did try doing this but did not work.

Comment: gpg: key E5267A6C: "Launchpad PPA for Ondřej Surý" not changed
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:              unchanged: 1

Comment: Which is your linux distribution? May it be too old?

Comment: root@webdev:/etc# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 7.11 (wheezy)
Release:        7.11
Codename:       wheezy

Comment: Debian 7 Long Term Support (LTS) expired on May 2018. Expired LTS usually don't allow updates, try to update to Debian 9 “Stretch”. You can use Virtualbox for this.